# Linq to SQL construct a custom object externally

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I want to achieve the following:

```
return  (from a in db.Tags
    select new TagItem
    {
        ID = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name
    });
```

..but i don't want to achieve it like that, because i need to use the exact same TagItem construction elsewhere (for a join)

So this is the intention, to call a method that constructs the TagItem for me:

```
return (from a in db.Tags
    select ConstructTagItem(a));
```

And the method constructs the object the same way:

```
private TagItem ConstructTagItem(Tag a)
{
    return new TagItem { ID = a.Id, Name = a.Name};
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Method 'TagItem ConstructTagItem(Tag)' has no supported translation to
>   SQL.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

**Solution (thanks Daniel Hilgarth):**

```
return db.Tags.Select(ConstructTagItem);
```

And the method:

```
private Expression<Func<Tag, TagItem>> ConstructTagItem
{
    get { return a => new TagItem {ID = a.Id Name = a.Name }; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You need to use an expression tree like this:

```
Expression<Func<Tag, TagItem>> constructTagItem = a => return new TagItem
                                                       { ID = a.Id, 
                                                         Name = a.Name};
```

And then you can use that expression instead of your method:

```
return db.Tags.Select(constructTagItem);
```

According to [this article](http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/01/16/using-lambda-expressions-with-linq-to-sql/) you need to use the method chains way of defining your query.

Comment: I have just figured out i had to use expressions, and then you wrote with this brilliant answer, thanks! ..i just have one question, I will try to explain it in my question, give me a sec

Comment: @Frost: IMHO, this should be a new question, because it is something else. I don't think it can be done the way your first example can be done. Basically, you just changed your complete question :) Please create a new question and accept my answer here.

Comment: Will do, but i wrote: "because i need to use the exact same TagItem construction elsewhere (for a join)"

Comment: @Frost: Yeah, I thought your join would also select a `TagItem` as the end result and not a `NewsTagItem`.